# Published by twine python package does not appear in repository

Tags: python, pypi, twine

I'm trying to publish my python package to private repository. I followed the official guide https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/ and everything seemed to be good. Here's terminal output:

```
(venv) C:\Users\xxx\PycharmProjects\my_package>twine upload --config-file .pypirc -r pypi dist/*
Uploading distributions to http://xxx/pypi/simple/
Enter your password:
Uploading my_package-0.1-py3-none-any.whl
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 8.03k/8.03k [00:01<00:00, 4.83kB/s]
Uploading my-package-0.1.tar.gz
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 7.40k/7.40k [00:00<00:00, 10.3kB/s]
```

But after publishing I can't see my package in repository neither by opening url in browser nor I can install it by pip.

I noticed that .whl comes with an underscore in name while .tar.gz comes with a dash. May it be be the issue?
How can I find out what is wrong?

Comment: Just a note from my personal experience with PIP. It might take some time for Your package to appear publicly. In my case it was more than 24 hours. It's worth to try `--repository testpypi dist/*` as well. It's a test repo where it should appear much faster.

Comment: Maybe your private repository isn't configured correctly?

Comment: Could you try  `http://xxx/pypi/` instead of `http://xxx/pypi/simple`.  Also try `python3 -m twine upload --repository-url <URL> --username <USERNAME> --password <PASSWORD> dist/*`

Comment: To be able to help you, more information on your setup configuration would be needed. Could you post the content of your `setup.py`/`setup.cfg`? Which commands did you use to build the the sdist tarball and the wheel?

Comment: You could also run `twine check dist/*` and `check-wheel-contents dist/*.whl` on your packages to see if any errors are reported.

Comment: What is your private repository? Devpi, Nexus, Artifactory, something else? This is probably the most crucial piece of information needed to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, it does not matter whether your package is uploaded to a private or a public repository. You can even not upload it to Git to publish it.

You can do that in 4 basic steps

- Create a python package
- Write `setup.py`
- Build the package
- Publish to PyPI via `twine`

### Create a python package

In the following example, the `demoverflow` folder contains `__init__.py`, which is making `demoverflow` a python package.

```
└── demoverflow
    ├── demo.py
    └── __init__.py
```

```
# demo.py

class Demo:
    ...
```

import `Demo` at `__init__.py` to be able to import it from `demoverflow` (like: `from demoverflow import Demo`)

```
# __init__.py

from demo import Demo
```

### Write `setup.py`

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="demoverflow",
    version="0.0.1",
    author="Firstname Lastname",
    author_email="<demoverflow@support.com>",
    description="My demo package",
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=[],
    keywords=['python'],
    classifiers=[
        "Development Status :: 1 - Planning",
        "Intended Audience :: Developers",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "Operating System :: Unix",
        "Operating System :: MacOS :: MacOS X",
        "Operating System :: Microsoft :: Windows",
    ]
)
```

**NOTE:** Before building the package, you should have the following file structure

```
├── demoverflow
│   ├── demo.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── setup.py
```

So `setup.py` and your package should be a neighbors

### Build the package

If you already installed `setuptools` then can run the following command to generate a dist folder

```
python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
```

### Publish to PyPI

This command will require the username and password of your PyPI account

```
python3 -m twine upload dist/*
```

Comment: thanks for comprehensive instruction. But the answer does not contain response to the question: how to find out what is wrong.

Comment: To answer exactly that question I need to see your project files, but you did not provide any. So I gave you a common answer.

Comment: You should consider updating your answer to use `python -m build --sdist --wheel` instead of the deprecated `python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel`. Ref: https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2021/10/setup-py-deprecated.html